# How to perform square root on a number in ARM assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, raspberry-pi4

Hi I'm new to ARM assembly and would like to know how to square root a number.

I'm currently using a raspberry pi to write and compile my code

For example:

```
.data

s1: .word 20

.text
.global main

main:
    LDR R1,=s1
    LDR R1,[R1]
    //How do I sqroot R1 from here?
```

Comment: First you need to decide whether you want an integer or a floating point result.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. A floating point result is what I am looking for as the end result.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way for such cases is to ask the C compiler for help.  Given this C code:

```
#include <math.h>

unsigned int mysqrt(unsigned int x) {
    return sqrt(x);
}
```

The compiler produces (slightly cleaned up):

```
mysqrt:
    vmov          s0, r0    @ move x to FP register
    vcvt.f64.u32  d16, s0   @ convert from int to double
    vsqrt.f64     d16, d16  @ compute square root
    vcvt.u32.f64  s0, d16   @ convert back to integer
    vmov          r0, s0    @ move back to general purpose register
    bx            lr
```

So that's what you should do, too.  If the number is in RAM initially, you can directly load it into a FP register like this:

```
    ldr           r0, =s1
    vldr          s0, [r1]
```